# Meteor Cordova persistent login

Tags: cordova, authentication, meteor

I'm using latest Meteor and Ironrouter in my application. The session is stored and resumed when using browser, my users don't need to login every time they access the application.

The problem is when building for Android using Cordova. Every time the application is closed properly, and then resumed, users need to login again. I've read that the random port issue should be solved in previous versions, but I just can't make it work. Any hints someone?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try [GroundDB](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db) for offline storage to store your user credentials. Also you can try [Persistent Sessions](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session). Just give it a try, may you get a hint!